# Running a Python animation via USB-Stick on an external "Monitor"?

Tags: python, animation, usb, television, screensaver

Basically my project involves displaying a certain animation on a **LG TV**. The only input I've been given is an **USB interface**.
From there on the goal is to display an animation or e.g. the current time, date, a countdown or anything alike which could be created with **Python** libraries.

-> So I need to somehow get a live animation / screensaver running via an USB-Stick on a LG TV. I searched for any Python packages that would enable me to do something like this, but unfortunately I wasn't able to find anything.

Does anyone have ANY idea on how to approach something like this? Feel free to ask any questions if the task isn't understandable.

Answer (score 1):

1. The easiest method would be to render the animation into a video container that the Smart TV understands. Like mkv or mp4

Python is an interpreted language and it seems wasteful to try get a way for the Smart TV to interpret the Python code.

Unless the animation has interaction - record it on a PC, save to USB and play on TV.

2. You could also use a Raspberry Pi or Pi Zero with a linux distribution running Python. Then just use the TV as an HDMI monitor.

Comment: First of all, thanks for your reply! The first option isn't possible (saving it to USB and playing it on a TV) due to the fact that some "animations" are live - e.g. the current time, in-going messages, etc.. How would you approach the first part of the first option (rendering into a container?); Your second idea is a good approach - how would I execute the Python script on the Raspberry Pi? Could you go in-depth with this idea?

Answer (score 1):

Do you know the scripts you would like to run?

1. Install Linux Raspbian (or other) on Raspberry Pi/Pi zero ($35/$11 ea.) at this time enabling or connecting it to WiFi - it sounds like you want values and items from the internet.
2. Install Python 3 on the Pi: https://installvirtual.com/how-to-install-python-3-8-on-raspberry-pi-raspbian/
3. Install the dependencies and libraries like: pip install pandas (or whatever libraries you need like matplotlib)
4. Run your Python script on the Raspberry Pi.
5. If you want to have the script execute on Startup (I assume you want this installation to be relatively hands-off) - https://www.instructables.com/id/Raspberry-Pi-Launch-Python-script-on-startup/

I would recommend adding a timeout on opening the script, with option to return to the OS and exit the script or you won't have much access to maintain the Pi (it will start executing the script immediately.)

6. Make sure you know how to do PuTTy access over SSH (or VNC) to maintain the Pi - as you don't want to try debug and code directly on the Pi - especially if this is a public display.

Comment: The "scripts" include (but are not limited to) displaying time, date, specific given animations.
I got some questions left after your reply:
- What Raspberry is suggested and what addons are necessary?
- How am I connecting to the LG TV? Via the HDMI port?
- How would you handle the "live rendering" / video creation part?

Comment: Hi - any Raspberry Pi will do - from 1-4 or a Pi Zero W. 

Yes, via the HDMI port - it's exactly like a PC display.

You'll display the render exactly as you would on the PC you coded the Python on when it executes. A Raspberry Pi is just a small but quite capable Linux machine.

Much of this you'll have to figure out yourself - it's sounding like you'd like me to design the architecture, and design a custom walkthrough of your specific  project.

Comment: @Phillip Joubert I don't want you to design the whole architecture, though it's my first time working with Raspberry Pi. I just ordered the Raspberry Pi 3 and I'd need some "inspirations" to how I shall set this whole thing up as well as which libraries I'd need to code such a live rendered video.

Comment: That I'm afraid you'll have to figure out based on your particular needs. You haven't given any details about what you would like shown or where the data for the animations might come from, what will be displayed etc.

If this is for a commercial application, I'd get used to making the animations on a normal PC before getting the Pi involved. The Pi's are just smaller computers and will make the TV's into PC monitors.

Comment: For starting purposes I want to implement a time as well as date tracker. I need a library to sort all the elements I'd be getting from different sources and display them on a continuous loop / requesting a refresh of said information every x ticks / second. Basically a "layouter" library.. Do you know anything for that?

Comment: Basically a library that I can use to set up a certain layout and which requests the information from other functions and which in the end livestreams a video file. Do you know anything alike?

Comment: You need to be more specific. What is a "certain layout"? Livestreaming or displaying? Livestream means encoding the display to a video bitstream and sending it to a streaming server, for YouTube, Facebook etc.

Plotly Dash might be the closest to what you would like.

You will also need to start with an actual example like "I want to fetch alll the tweets from Twitter with the hashtag #...."and pull them in as objects to Plotly - then display them. That's also a good google search term.